# memcpy and string literal. does it check and consider null termination -- C

Tags: c

I have a code

```
char str1[15];
char str2[15];
memcpy(str1,"abcdef",6);
memcpy(str2,"abcdef",6);
```

so str1 should have null termination at index 7.
but when I do `printf("--%d--",strlen(str1));` it prints `--9--` which is why its making me think that `memcpy` is not considering null termination when copy into `str1` the string literal `"abcdef".

so shouldnt it also read null termination or is something I did in printf gives me print `--9--`?

Comment: `memcpy` copies memory, that's all. If you want to copy a string use `strcpy`.

Comment: `memcpy(str1,"abcdef",6);` copies **6** bytes... no `'\0'`, you probably want `memcpy(str1, "abcdef", 7);` or `memcpy(str1, "abcdef", sizeof "abcdef");`

Comment: @pmg `memcpy(str1, "abcdef", 7)` this works perfect. is it at index 7 writing `\0`

Comment: Having *magic* numbers like `6` or `7` in the comments above is very practice leading to future bug.

Answer (score 2):

`void * memcpy( void *destination, const void *source, size_t num );` just copies `num` bytes of memory, pointed by `source`, to another memory pointed by `destination` pointer.

The methods which deal with copying of null-terminated strings are

```
char * strcpy ( char *destination, const char *source);
char * strncpy ( char *destination, const char *source, size_t num);
```

Based on your example, you need to use [`strncpy`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/):

```
char str1[15];
char str2[15];
strncpy(str1,"abcdef",7);
strncpy(str2,"abcdef",7);
```

`str1` and `str2` will hold "abcdef" at the end.

If you just want to copy the whole string up to the size of `str1` or `str2` then you can do the following

```
#define STR_LEN 15

char str1[STR_LEN];
char str2[STR_LEN];
strncpy(str1,"abcdef", STR_LEN);
strncpy(str2,"abcdef", STR_LEN);
```

NOTE:

As the documentation of `strncpy` states:

> No null-character is implicitly appended at the end of destination if source is longer than num. Thus, in this case, destination shall not be considered a null terminated C string (reading it as such would overflow).

Comment: `strncpy()` is not designed to work with *strings*. In this example it will not work!!

Comment: @pmg why not? It will do exactly what it suppose to do. Was your account hacked? `strncpy` was not designed to work with strings???

Comment: `strncpy` sometimes forgets the null character and does not care about where it is copying to. It gives the illusion of being more safe

Comment: @EdHeal: The strncpy function is poorly named, but its purpose is to convert null-terminated strings to null-*padded* strings, and it works perfectly for that purpose.

Comment: @supercat - That was my point - it is poorly named

Comment: After the changes it works... but, again, `strncpy()` was not designed to work with strings.

Comment: @pmg: It's designed to work with zero-padded strings, which are safer and more space-efficient than C strings when used in structures, provided that one uses them properly.

Comment: *`strncpy()` is designed to work with `char data[6] = "foobar";` which is not a string*

Comment: @pmg: The term "string" can be used to refer to multiple kinds of character sequence, of which zero-terminated strings are but one [if they were the only kind of 'string', then referring to them as "zero-terminated strings" or "C strings" would be redundant].

Answer (score 2):

[memcpy](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html) just copy a number of bytes, whatever they are. In your case, it copies 6 bytes from a string of 6 characters and hence do **not** copy the null byte at the end of string.

Better code could be written.

Given:

```
char str1[15];
char str2[15];
char *p = "abcdef";
```

This will copy "abcdef" and the nul byte to str1 and str2:

```
memcpy(str1, p, strlen(p) + 1);
memcpy(str2, p, strlen(p) + 1);
```

But this is not very good because str1 and str2 array could be overflown if the string is to long!

It is much better to use `strncpy` which copies the string, taking account of the nul terminating byte, the length of the string and the maximum length of the destination:

```
strncpy(str1, p, sizeof(str1));
strncpy(str2, p, sizeof(str2));
```

**Warning**: If there is no null byte among the first n bytes of the source, the string placed in destination will not be null-terminated. See [strncpy man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html).

Comment: can u please tell where I can find list of string.h and other header files that works on these `string literal` and also on arrays like I have maintained entire rational database table in the form of `multiple dimensional` array like storing students and with ids and names and other details. complete full fledged tabular data in some-d array

Comment: I don't know if such list of header files exists. Anyway, for you to learn how C strings and arrays work, you should better find a good book about C language.

Comment: then is there any list of functions that will be needed for work that I like to do. can u think of those functions please. searching tabular data stored in arrays.

Comment: I will do this work any way hard way or little bit with ease of functions.

Comment: For your problem of *searching tabular data stored in arrays*, please open a new specific question. This is required by StackOverflow rules. We cannot simply chat here to solve all your problems but I'll be happy to help you for each question (In the sense of StackOverflow) you ask provided I can help.

Comment: @user786 You can start from [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/header) and follow the links.

Comment: @Bob__ The OP is using C not C++. C and C++ are two **different** languages and you should not direct him to a C++ reference!

Comment: True. That's why I linked to the **C** section of that reference. Please note the Standard references at the bottom of that page, followed by a *link* to the C++ documentation for those headers. All the linked pages about those C headers follow this pattern.